# Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am new to unit testing. I use `react typescript`
I wrote a unit test that fails at the first line, because of `import`.
How can I config this to work ?

**error** :

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

Details:

/app/node_modules/axios/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

> 1 | import {AxiosError, AxiosInstance, AxiosResponse} from "axios";
```

**config** :
package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.7",
        "@testing-library/dom": "^8.19.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@types/testing-library__react": "^10.2.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
        "babel-jest": "^29.3.1",
        "eslint": "8.30.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
        "jest": "^29.3.1",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.20",
        "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
        "prettier": "^2.8.1",
        "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
        "ts-jest": "^29.0.3"
    }
```

balel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: {
                    node: 'current',
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

jest.config.js

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: "ts-jest",
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern: `'^.+\\.ts?$'` is wrong.

## Fix

It should be: `'^.+\\.tsx?$'`.

## More

There might be other issues as well. Recommend creating a new project and comparing yours with that.

From the official docs: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options

Answer (score 1):

**Why does this error occur?**

The 1.x.x version of axios changed the module type from CommonJS to ECMAScript.

**The 0.x.x version of axios index.js file**

```
module.exports = require('./lib/axios');
```

**The 1.x.x version of axiox index.js file**

```
import axios from './lib/axios.js';
export default axios;
```

Basically, jest runs on Node.js environment, so it uses modules following the CommonJS. If you want to use axios up to 1.x.x, you have to transpile the JavaScript module from ECMAScript type to CommonJS type. Jest ignores /node_modules/ directory to transform basically.

So you have to override transformIgnorePatterns option. There are two ways to override transformIgnorePatterns option.

**jest.config.js**

So how do you use config.js ,you can replace the parameter

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
```

on

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!axios)"],
```

**package.json**

you can add a setting for just in your package.json file

```
    {
  ...other options
  "jest": {
    "preset": "your project",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules\/(?!axios)"]
  }
}
```

**alternative solution**

in the package.json you can specify a parameter for the test script *"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns "node_modules/(?!axios)/"",*

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!axios)/\"",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```